# Can,t access selectedCategoryId value outside the method

Tags: android

Im getting value for selectedCategoryId that is defined in select method, in another method initCat, getting 0 value for selectedCategoryId, is there any way to get value from one method to another method in the same class, help me out

here is my code

```
package com.panaceasoft.myPack.fragments;
public class BusinessRegisterFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ArrayList < PCityData > cityArrayList;
    private ArrayList < PSubCategoryData > subCatArrayList;
    private ArrayList < PCityData > cityDataSet;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_business_register, container, false);

        initData();

        initUI();

        initCat();

        return view;
    }

    private void initData() {}

    public void initUI() {

        cityPopupContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.choose_city_container);
        cityPopupContainer.removeAllViews();

        catPopupContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.choose_cat_container);
        catPopupContainer.removeAllViews();

        subCatPopupContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.choose_sub_cat_container);
        subCatPopupContainer.removeAllViews();

        PPopupSingleSelectView pPopupSingleSelectView = new PPopupSingleSelectView(getActivity(), selectCategoryString, GlobalData.categoryDatas, "");
        pPopupSingleSelectView.setOnSelectListener(new SelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void Select(View view, int position, CharSequence text) {}

            @Override
            public void Select(View view, int position, CharSequence text, int id) {
                selectedCategoryId = id;
                selectedCategoryName = text.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void Select(View view, int position, CharSequence text, int id, float additionalPrice) {}
        });
        catPopupContainer.addView(pPopupSingleSelectView);

        imageToUplaod.setOnClickListener(this);
        bUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        bSelectImage.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnRegisterBusiness.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
            Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                doRegister();
            }
        });

        btnCancelBusiness.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
            Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doCancel();
            }
        });

        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);

    }
    private void initCat() {
        requestSubCategory(Config.APP_API + Config.GET_SUBCAT_BY_CAT + "?cat_id=" + selectedCategoryId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a minimal example. We don't need your whole project here.

Comment: Just want to know how to get variable value from one method to another

Comment: @amit: and we just want a minimal example. If you cant bother to make a good question, we wont bother to give a proper response. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , edit your question, and then come back.

Comment: I updated it  as minimal as  i can

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void initCat(int catID) {
        requestSubCategory(Config.APP_API + Config.GET_SUBCAT_BY_CAT +"?cat_id="+catID);
}
```

and call from `select()` method.

```
@Override
public void Select(View view, int position, CharSequence text, int id) {

    selectedCategoryId = id;
    selectedCategoryName = text.toString();
    initCat(id);

}
```

Comment: thanx bt sorry I think I didnot explain my question properly, I hav update the question, in select method im getting value bt outside that in initCat() method there is 0 value for selectedCategoryId

Comment: how do you know that you are getting `selectedCategoryId` ? have you tried to add Log in select method ?

Comment: In logcat I display it,

Comment: dont see logcat there. and  if you are getting value there then u must get value outside of that.

Comment: or there may be case of calling  `initCat()` before `select()` method. Check that you are calling `initCat()` method after selecting value. @amit see updated answer.

Comment: I called `initCat()` method inside `selec()` just after `selectedCategoryId`, its work bt it replicated every time I select value

Comment: yes otherwise how can u get value of selectedCategoryId ?